# Checkstyle 6.2 Installed in eclipse but not visible

Tags: checkstyle

I installed Checkstyle 6.2 in eclipse Kepler 4.3.2 with net.sf.eclipsecs-updatesite_6.2.0.201501101308-bin file .Checkstyle is getting displayed in the Installed Softwares list but is not visible in Windows-> Preferences.

Started eclipse with eclipse -clean -refresh also but still checkstyle is not visible

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to solve this:

First, perhaps it's because you have installed Eclipse somewhere you are not allowed to write to, like in "Program Files". Try this:

```
uninstall checkstyle plugin cleanly with the uninstall feature
Open eclipse.exe with admin rights
reinstalled checkstyle, and restart eclipse.
```

Otherwise, try this. This worked for me in Eclipse Luna:

```
Unistall checkstyle 6.2.0 and install Checkstyle 5.6.1. 
Go to Help -> Install new software 
Insert this link : 
    http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-cs/files/updatesite/5.6.1/
```